# How to prevent cascading of delete with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a class `Person` which has a unidirectional one-to-one relationship with another class `Passport` (Person know the Passport, but not the other way around).

```
class Person {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(...)
    private Passport passport;
}
```

Now, if I delete person, the passport is deleted as well. Since I haven't specified a cascady type, there should be no cascading at all.

How can I prevent the cascading of delete?

Comment: Can't you Specify the CascadeType top not include removal. CascadeType.PERSIST                                                       https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html

Comment: The default `cascade="none"` specifies that no operations are to be cascaded. Otherwise, you might not need cascade at all.